# Swift: Conditional String transformations

Tags: swift, string

**How can one translate a given string, according to the following criteria?**

- All words greater than 3 characters should be translated to the word
  "bingo"
- Capitalization must be maintained
- Punctuation within words (e.g. we'll) can be discarded, all other punctuation must be maintained.

**My code so far:**

```
// *** Using For loop ***
var text = "I'll BUY THAT for a $1234 dollars!"
var textComponents = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

for i in 0 ..< textComponents.count {
    // -TODO: add code to maintain capitalization & punctuation (i.e.: !, $)
    if textComponents[i].count > 3 {
        textComponents[i] = "bingo"
    }
}

textComponents.joined(separator: " ")


// *** Using Map/Filter ***
var text = "I'll BUY THAT for a $1234 dollars!"
var textComponents = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
textComponents.map {
    // -TODO: add code to maintain capitalization & punctuation (i.e.: !, $)
    if $0.count > 3 {
        // ERROR: Not able reassign $0
        $0 = "bingo"
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

**Given string:** "I'll BUY THAT for a $1234 dollars!"

**Expected translation:** "Bingo BUY BINGO for a $bingo bingo!"

Comment: `$` is not a punctuation symbol, it's a currency symbol. If `we'll` is considered to be one word, do you actually have rules what is a word?

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan - correct; the $ symbol should be maintained too. `we'll` would be one word with greater than 3 characters, and therefore it should be translated to `bingo`.

Comment: Step 1: Use a regular expression to replace what you need by `bingo`, e.g. `string.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\w']{3,}", with: "bingo", options: .regularExpression)`. Improve the regular expression to cover exactly the use case you want.

Comment: Step 2: Use `NSRegularExpression` to do the same but decide whether to use `bingo` or `BINGO` depending on the case of characters in the captured text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need at least three replacing words like the following. It may not be complete as your requirements are not so fixed now.

```
  let raw = "I'll BUY THAT for a $1234 dollar!".replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[A-Z][[a-z0-9]\\']{3,}", with: "Bingo", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[A-Z\\']{4,}", with: "BINGO", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[a-z'\\d]{4,}", with: "bingo", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

  print(raw) // Bingo BUY BINGO for a $bingo bingo!
```

Comment: Thanks @E.Coms - this is very close! However, the expected translation is: "Bingo BUY BINGO for a $bingo bingo!" (Note the `BINGO` in all caps). The output of raw is: "Bingo BUY Bingo for a $bingo bingo!" (Note the `Bingo` which should be `BINGO`). I don't think your second replacingOccurrence is working: `.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\b[A-Z']{4,}", with: "BINGO", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)`, which is not replacing "THAT" to "BINGO".